# Entry point issue in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following program :

```
let readStoriesInQAForm = 
    printfn "Inside the let!"
    0 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "Ah! entering point to the main!"
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I was expecting to get the following output (since main is the entry point, and there is no function call):

```
Ah! entering point to the main!
```

But I get this, when I compiler and run it in VS 2013:

```
Inside the let!
Ah! entering point to the main!
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not declaring a function, you're declaring a value. It's missing `()`:

```
let readStoriesInQAForm() =
```

Answer (score 7):

As John Palmer describes in his answer, F# code is executed from top to bottom. The `let` keyword binds a value to a name - in this case, the value `0` is bound to the `readStoriesInQAForm` name.

Apart from primitive values, you can also bind *functions* to names; F# is a *Functional* programming language, so functions are values too. If you bind a function to a name, you can execute that function by invoking it.

However, `readStoriesInQAForm` isn't a function - it's a primitive value (`0`), and it gets bound before `main` is called, in order to make that value available for `main`. In this particular case, the way the `let` binding is defined, it has a **side-effect** of printing to Standard Out when the binding occurs. (In general, in Functional Programming, the more you can avoid side-effects, the better.)

If you want to avoid this behaviour, change the `let` binding from a a primitive value to a function:

```
let readStoriesInQAForm () = 
    printfn "Inside the let!"
    0
```

Better yet would be to bind the name to the value without any side-effect:

```
let readStoriesInQAForm = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

In a F# program, the code is essentially run from top to bottom, so that any values needed later are available.

For example, if you had written:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "Ah! entering point to the main!"
    printfn readStoriesInQAForm
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The observed behaviour makes perfect sense as it would be illogical to jump out of main to calculate a constant value.

To avoid this issue, you want to make `readStoriesInQAForm` a function, like so:

```
let readStoriesInQAForm() = ...
```