# Why do I get different results at runtime based on when I execute my recursive function?

Tags: recursion, f#

I have a recursive function defined in a module like so:

```
module Domain:
    let rec myFunc params=
        // do some stuff

    let callFuncWithDefault () = 
        myFunc someDefaultParams
```

From my main function I can now call this and everything works as expected:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let result = Domain.callFuncWithDefault()
```

However, if I change callFuncWithDefault to look like this:

```
let callFuncWithDefault = myFunc someDefaultParams
```

I would expect callFuncWithDefault to become the result of calling myFunc with the default params and allow me to access it in the main function like so:

```
let result = Domain.callFuncWithDefault
```

However, I find that the main function is never even executed in this scenario - I can only assume that myFunc is recursing infinitely (although I can't see how).  What am I missing? Why would this work fine if I defer the execution to the main function but appear to not work if I try and calculate the value in my Domain module?

Edit:  The actual code that is causing this problem is presented here:

```
open System


module Domain = 
    type Position = Position of int*int
    type Queen = {Position : Position}
    type Board = {Queens : Queen list}

    let canTake {Position = position1} {Position = (Position (x2,y2))} =
        let (Position (x1,y1)) = position1
        x1 = x2 || y1 = y2 || Math.Abs x1-x2 = Math.Abs y1-y2

    let canPlaceQueen {Queens = queens} queen = 
        let canTakeQueen = canTake queen
        List.exists canTakeQueen queens
        |>  not

    let rec solutionsForX x {Queens = queens} =
        match x with
        | i when i > 0 && i < 9 ->
            [1..8]
            |>  List.map (fun y -> {Position = Position (x,y)})
            |>  List.filter (canPlaceQueen {Queens = queens})
            |>  List.map (fun q -> {Queens = q::queens})
            |>  List.fold (fun solutions board -> List.append solutions (solutionsForX (x+1) board)) []
        | _     -> [{Queens = queens}]

    let print {Queens = queens} = 
        printfn "%A" queens 

    let findSolutions = solutionsForX 1 {Queens = []}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "starting..."
    let solutions = Domain.findSolutions
    solutions 
    |>  List.length
    |>  printfn "%i"
    solutions
    |>  List.iter Domain.print
    printfn "press any key to end"
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I realise that some of this code (such as the function signature of canTake) are a bit odd - this is purely an exercise in teaching myself f# - but I can't see how any of it causes the problem...

Comment: See here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112601/entry-point-issue-in-f

Comment: I understand that I am changing callFuncWithDefault from a function to a value (granted I could rename it to reflect the change) - what I don't understand is when I define it as a function and call from main it returns the result I expect, but when I try to define it as a value in my Domain module the recursion appears to be infinite....

Comment: I think without a more complete example we won't be able to find a solution.

Comment: I just cut and pasted the code you have into a new F# application project and it seemed to run fine - printed many position then asked for a key before exiting.

Comment: The line `let callFuncWithDefault = myFunc someDefaultParams` will execute before `main` since it's part of the module initialisation. Something must be going wrong in `myFunc` so what's the result of attaching a debugger to it?

Comment: Something odd appears to be happening - I begin execution and my console just sits there forever - once I press pause at any point I can step into the code and when I then press continue I get the answer as expected - sorry guys this feels like it was a wild goose chase.....

Comment: and if I execute without debugging it works fine.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might be able to reproduce your issue.  When I run from command line, or start with Ctrl-F5 ("start without debugging"), it runs near-instantly (after removing the printing).  When I run with F5 ("debug") it appears to hang before the first line of `main` is executed.  Is that what you are seeing?

Well, it isn't completely hung, it is just running very slowly... Execution without the debugger takes under 1 second on my machine, but with debugger attached it takes *over 2 minutes* before the first line of `main` is executed.  Have you tried letting it run for that long?

I also notice (in VS 2013) that if I enabled Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" (i.e. use "old" debugger, not the new one released with VS 2013), then the perf problem disappears.  I'd suggest trying that, as well.

Comment: Just tried and it's exactly as you describe - actually takes close to 5 min to run in debug on my machine!  With the old debugger enabled, it is near instantaneous.  Cheers!  Bug with the VS2013 debugger I guess?

Comment: Glad it's understood and you can work around. Must be some bug/behavior change in 2013 debugger. I've filed a bug, we'll see where it goes.

Answer (score -1):

This simple code works fine for me:

```
module Domain =
    let rec myFunc ps=
        match ps with
        | [] -> 0
        | h::t -> h + (myFunc t) 

    let callFuncWithDefault () = 
        myFunc [1;2;3;4;5;6]

    let deferred = myFunc [1;2;3;4;5;6]

let result = Domain.callFuncWithDefault()
let result2 = Domain.deferred

printfn "%A" result
printfn "%A" result2
```

*update:*
If You add `main` function it is also working:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let result = Domain.callFuncWithDefault()
    let result2 = Domain.deferred

    printfn "%A" result
    printfn "%A" result2
    1 //just to return something
```

So it seems that the issue is somewhere inside Your `myFunc` function.

*update 2*:
Your specific code executes on my machine and gives some result:

> [{Queens =    [{Position = Position (8,5);}; {Position = Position
>   (7,2);};
>       {Position = Position (6,4);}; {Position = Position (5,7);};
>       {Position = Position (4,8);}; {Position = Position (3,6);};
>       {Position = Position (2,3);}; {Position = Position (1,1);}];};
>
> ...